# JSONKIt serialize NSDIctionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How to use JSONKit to serialize a NSDictionary into string? I couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Serializing Interface" section of the [JSONKit README](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/blob/master/README.md) states that the library adds a method `JSONString` to `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSString`. This looks like what you're after.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary withObjectsAndKeys:...];
NSString *JSON = [dictionary JSONString];
```